# Zooming within pagingScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

A follow on from the question I asked yesterday.

I have a paging scrollView that only pages in the y-axis. At the moment I have it working that I have an array of UIImageViews containing different UIImages and the photoScroller works as i'd expect but when I try to add the imageView as a subview of another scrollView to allow pinching and zooming it breaks the gallery.

By breaks I mean it only loads the first image but the spaces left there for the other images and not pinching happens.

```
     - (void)loadView{
```

// Creates 4 images from the file names
     UIImage *img0 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"29.png"];
     UIImage *img1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"33.png"];
     UIImage *img2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMAG0085.JPG"];
     UIImage *img3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DSC00081.JPG"];

NSMutableArray *imgArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:img0,img1,img2, img3, nil]; //Places images into array


CGRect pagingScrollViewFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]; // Creates initial scrollViewFrame to be the size of the screen
pagingScrollViewFrame.origin.x -= 10; //moves it 10px to the left
pagingScrollViewFrame.size.width += 20; //adds 20px to the right creating a 10px blank buffer either side
pagingScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:pagingScrollViewFrame]; //Creates the pagingScrollView with the size specified with the frame
pagingScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES; //allow paging
pagingScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor]; //background black
pagingScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(pagingScrollViewFrame.size.width * [imgArray count], pagingScrollViewFrame.size.height); //sets the width of the scroll view depending on the number in amges in the array.

self.view = pagingScrollView; //add the pagingScrollView to the main view

for (int i=0; i < [imgArray count]; i++) { //loop to add the images to an imageView and then add them to the paging ScrollView

    /*--------Gets the image from the array and places it in an imageView------*/
    UIImageView *page = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [imgArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    page.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    page.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    //[page.setClipsToBounds:YES];
    CGRect cgRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGSize cgSize = cgRect.size;
    [page setFrame:CGRectMake((i*pagingScrollViewFrame.size.width)+10, 0, cgSize.width, cgSize.height)];

    /*--------Creates Zooming scrollView and adds the imageView as a subView------*/

    UIScrollView *zoomingScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:cgRect];
    zoomingScrollView.delegate = self;
    zoomingScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 4.0;
    zoomingScrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;

    [zoomingScrollView addSubview:page];
    [pagingScrollView addSubview:zoomingScrollView];
     }}

   - (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
  NSArray *array = [scrollView subviews];
  return [array lastObject];
 }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
zoomingScrollView.frame = CGRectMake((i*pagingScrollViewFrame.size.width)+10, 0, cgSize.width, cgSize.height)];
page.frame = zoomingScrollView.bounds;
```